# Meaning of Bronze, Silver, etc. in regards to competitive TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2, competitive-gaming

I am currently looking for a team in TF2. I've look on different forums, and I have noticed that people often speak about "bronze, silver" etc... when they present themselves for joining a team.

I was wondering what is the meaning of this ranking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iron and Silver are two of the divisions used in US competitive play. The full list, from best to worst goes:

- Platinum
- Gold (Only in Highlander)
- Silver
- Steel
- Iron

Teams in competitive leagues will play teams from the same division. This means teams will mostly play teams of a similar skill level. Different leagues have different rules for what division a new team can start in but all will bump teams up or down if they perform well or poorly.

Comment: OP mentions bronze, but this answer does not contain it.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Batophobia Bronze isn't an actual division, at least not in any leagues I know of.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the metallic leagues are unique to UGC, not US competitive play in general.

Comment: These divisions are specific to UGC. There's not really a standard. For example, CEVO has Open (equivalent to the higher UGC leagues), Main, and I think they were considering Professional? This may be out of date but it's just an example.